# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Stage' is undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do this tutorial:

http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-simple-windows-8-game-with-javascript-game-basics-createjseaseljs/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>CatapultGame</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- CatapultGame references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
    <script src="js/CreateJS/easeljs-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/CreateJS/preloadjs-0.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

and there is JS file

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232509


(function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences = true;

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

    WinJS.strictProcessing();

    var canvas, context, stage;
    var bgImage, p1Image, p2Image, ammoImage, p1lives, p2lives, title, endGameImage;
    var bgBitmap, p1Bitmap, p2Bitmap, ammoBitmap;
    var preload;

    // Current Display Factor. Because the orignal assumed a 800x480 screen
    var SCALE_X = window.innerWidth / 800;
    var SCALE_Y = window.innerHeight / 480;
    var MARGIN = 25;
    var GROUND_Y = 390 * SCALE_Y;

    function initialize() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        preload = new createjs.PreloadJS();
        preload.onComplete = prepareGame;
        var manifest = [
            { id: "screenImage", src: "images/Backgrounds/gameplay_screen.png" },
            { id: "redImage", src: "images/Catapults/Red/redIdle/redIdle.png" },
            { id: "blueImage", src: "images/Catapults/Blue/blueIdle/blueIdle.png" },
            { id: "ammoImage", src: "images/Ammo/rock_ammo.png" },
            { id: "winImage", src: "images/Backgrounds/victory.png" },
            { id: "loseImage", src: "images/Backgrounds/defeat.png" },
            { id: "blueFire", src: "images/Catapults/Blue/blueFire/blueCatapult_fire.png" },
            { id: "redFire", src: "images/Catapults/Red/redFire/redCatapult_fire.png" },
        ];

        preload.loadManifest(manifest);


        stage = new Stage(canvas); <<<--------
    }

    function prepareGame() {
        bgImage = preload.getResult("screenImage").result;
        bgBitmap = new Bitmap(bgImage);
        bgBitmap.scaleX = SCALE_X;
        bgBitmap.scaleY = SCALE_Y;
        stage.addChild(bgBitmap);

        stage.update();
    }

    function gameLoop() {

    }

    function update() {

    }

    function draw() {

    }

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
                // your application here.
            } else {
                // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
                // Restore application state here.
            }
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        }
    };

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
        // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
        // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the
        // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
        // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
        // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
        // args.setPromise().
    };

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialize, false);

    app.start();
})();
```

But When I'm trying to run the project, I get and error saying "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Stage' is undefined", in the marked place in my code.

What I did wrong?

Comment: where is this script located? (which file is it ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a newer version of EaselJS (3.1 is the current version), some things need to change.  The most common is that the EaselJS and PreloadJS objects are now wrapped in the createjs namespace.  So the line from the tutorial:

```
stage = new Stage(canvas);
```

becomes

```
stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
```

and the line

```
bgBitmap = new Bitmap(bgImage);
```

becomes

```
bgBitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(bgImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that Stage class is defined in your application, that why you getting error on line stage = new Stage(canvas);

please have cross check whether "Stage" class has been defined in any of your JS files(which is included in HTML)

that may be the problem !!!!

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention(sorry for this) that I'm using easelJS and preloadJS libraries. So, I only have 3 .js files: default.js, easeljs.js and preloadjs.js and 1 HTML file(default.html)

EDIT: I just change "stage = new Stage(canvas);" to "stage = new stage(canvas);" (with small "s") and now I get another error, saying " JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action".

Comment: Im not aware of easelJS and preloadJS libraries. by seeing your problem, it state that Stage class is undefined, which means its unable to get reference of class Stage. simply i can say as, a function Stage is not defined in your loaded application.

Comment: Well, it's more undefined errors I get if I delete this line(stage = new Stage(canvas);) . When it says : "JavaScript runtime error: 'Bitmap' is undefined" in the "bgBitmap = new Bitmap(bgImage);" line ;///

Comment: FINALLY !!!! I get it. I just needed to replace "stage = new Stage(canvas);" to "stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);"