# 0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action

Tags: javascript

I am reading and trying to do this tutorial:
http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-simple-windows-8-game-with-javascript-input-and-sound/

Yesterday, I wrote in this forum with one error, and solved it, but today, I'm in the final one and getting another error.

My default.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>CatapultGame</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- CatapultGame references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
    <script src="js/CreateJS/easeljs-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/CreateJS/preloadjs-0.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

and default.js file :

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232509
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
    WinJS.strictProcessing();

    var canvas, context, stage;
    var bgImage, p1Image, p2Image, ammoImage, p1Lives, p2Lives, title, endGameImage;
    var bgBitmap, p1Bitmap, p2Bitmap, ammoBitmap;
    var preload;

    // calculate display scale factor  - original game assets assume 800x480
    var SCALE_X = window.innerWidth / 800;
    var SCALE_Y = window.innerHeight / 480;
    var MARGIN = 25;
    var GROUND_Y = 390 * SCALE_Y;

    var LIVES_PER_PLAYER = 3;
    var player1Lives = LIVES_PER_PLAYER;
    var player2Lives = LIVES_PER_PLAYER;

    var isShotFlying = false;
    var playerTurn = 1;
    var playerFire = false;
    var shotVelocity;

    var MAX_SHOT_POWER = 10;
    var GRAVITY = 0.07;

    var isAiming = false;
    var aimPower = 1;
    var aimStart, aimVector;

    var FIRE_SOUND_FILE = "/sounds/CatapultFire.wav";
    var HIT_SOUND_FILE = "/sounds/BoulderHit.wav";
    var EXPLODE_SOUND_FILE = "/sounds/CatapultExplosion.wav";
    var LOSE_SOUND_FILE = "/sounds/Lose.wav";
    var AIM_SOUND_FILE = "/sounds/RopeStretch.wav";
    var WIN_SOUND_FILE = "/sounds/Win.wav";


    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
                // your application here.
            } else {
                // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
                // Restore application state here.
            }
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        }
    };

    function initialize() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        canvas.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", endAim, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", adjustAim, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", beginAim, false)

        **var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);** <<========== HERE IS THE ERROR LINE !!!!

        // use preloadJS to get sounds and images loaded before starting

        preload = new createjs.PreloadJS();
        preload.onComplete = prepareGame;
        var manifest = [
        { id: "screenImage", src: "images/Backgrounds/gameplay_screen.png" },
        { id: "redImage", src: "images/Catapults/Red/redIdle/redIdle.png" },
        { id: "blueImage", src: "images/Catapults/Blue/blueIdle/blueIdle.png" },
        { id: "ammoImage", src: "images/Ammo/rock_ammo.png" },
        { id: "winImage", src: "images/Backgrounds/victory.png" },
        { id: "loseImage", src: "images/Backgrounds/defeat.png" },
        { id: "blueFire", src: "images/Catapults/Blue/blueFire/blueCatapultFire.png" },
        { id: "redFire", src: "images/Catapults/Red/redFire/redCatapultFire.png" },
        { id: "hitSound", src: HIT_SOUND_FILE },
        { id: "explodeSound", src: EXPLODE_SOUND_FILE },
        { id: "fireSound", src: FIRE_SOUND_FILE },
        { id: "loseSound", src: LOSE_SOUND_FILE },
        { id: "aimSound", src: AIM_SOUND_FILE },
        { id: "winSound", src: WIN_SOUND_FILE }
        ];
        preload.loadManifest(manifest);
    }

    function prepareGame()
    {
        // draw Bg first, others appear on top
        bgImage = preload.getResult("screenImage").result;
        bgBitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(bgImage);
        bgBitmap.scaleX = SCALE_X;
        bgBitmap.scaleY = SCALE_Y;
        stage.addChild(bgBitmap);

        // draw p1 catapult
        p1Image = preload.getResult("redImage").result;
        p1Bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(p1Image);
        p1Bitmap.scaleX = SCALE_X;
        p1Bitmap.scaleY = SCALE_Y;
        p1Bitmap.x = MARGIN;
        p1Bitmap.y = GROUND_Y - p1Image.height * SCALE_Y;
        stage.addChild(p1Bitmap);

        // draw p2 catapult and flip
        p2Image = preload.getResult("blueImage").result;
        p2Bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(p2Image);
        p2Bitmap.regX = p2Image.width;
        p2Bitmap.scaleX = -SCALE_X; // flip from right edge
        p2Bitmap.scaleY = SCALE_Y;
        p2Bitmap.x = canvas.width - MARGIN - (p2Image.width * SCALE_X);
        p2Bitmap.y = GROUND_Y - (p2Image.height * SCALE_Y);
        stage.addChild(p2Bitmap);

        // draw the boulder, and hide for the moment
        ammoImage = preload.getResult("ammoImage").result;
        ammoBitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(ammoImage);
        ammoBitmap.scaleX = SCALE_X;
        ammoBitmap.scaleY = SCALE_Y;
        ammoBitmap.visible = false; // hide until fired
        stage.addChild(ammoBitmap);

        // player 1 lives
        p1Lives = new createjs.Text("Lives Left : " + player1Lives, "20px sans-serif", "red");
        p1Lives.scaleX = SCALE_X;
        p1Lives.scaleY = SCALE_Y;
        p1Lives.x = MARGIN;
        p1Lives.y = MARGIN * SCALE_Y;
        stage.addChild(p1Lives);

        //player 2 lives
        p2Lives = new createjs.Text("Lives Left : " + player2Lives, "20px sans-serif", "red");
        p2Lives.scaleX = SCALE_X;
        p2Lives.scaleY = SCALE_Y;
        p2Lives.x = canvas.width - p2Lives.getMeasuredWidth() * SCALE_X - MARGIN;
        p2Lives.y = MARGIN * SCALE_Y;
        stage.addChild(p2Lives);

        // game title
        title = new createjs.Text("Catapult Wars", "30px sans-serif", "black");
        title.scaleX = SCALE_X;
        title.scaleY = SCALE_Y;
        title.x = canvas.width / 2 - (title.getMeasuredWidth() * SCALE_X) / 2
        title.y = 30 * SCALE_Y;
        stage.addChild(title);

        stage.update();
        startGame();
    }

    function startGame()
    {
        Ticker.setInterval(window.requestAnimationFrame);
        Ticker.addListener(gameLoop);
    }

    function gameLoop()
    {
        update();
        draw();
    }

    function update() {
        if (isShotFlying)
        {
            // shot in the air
            ammoBitmap.x += shotVelocity.x;
            ammoBitmap.y += shotVelocity.y;

            shotVelocity.y += GRAVITY; //apply gravity to the y(height) values only, obviously

            if (ammoBitmap.y + ammoBitmap.image.height >= GROUND_Y ||
                ammoBitmap.x <= 0 ||
                ammoBitmap.x + ammoBitmap.image.width >= canvas.width)
            {
                // missed
                isShotFlying = false; //stop shot
                ammoBitmap.visible = false;
                playerTurn = playerTurn % 2 + 1; // invert player ( switch between 1 and 2)
            }
            else if (playerTurn == 1)
            {
                if (checkHit(p2Bitmap)) {
                    // Hit
                    p2Lives.text = "Lives Left : " + --player2Lives;
                    processHit();
                }
            }
            else if (playerTurn == 2)
            {
                if (checkHit(p1Bitmap))
                {
                    // Hit
                    p1Lives.text = "Lives Left : " + --player1Lives;
                    processHit();
                }
            }

        }
            // No current shot, should either player fire ?
        else if (playerTurn == 1)
        {
            // does the player want to fire ?
            if (playerFire)
            {
                playerFire = false;
                ammoBitmap.x = p1Bitmap.x + (p1Bitmap.image.width * SCALE_X / 2);
                ammoBitmap.y = p1Bitmap.y;
                shotVelocity = aimVector;
                 fireShot();


            }
        }
        else if (playerTurn == 2)
        {
            // AI automatically fires (randomly on it's turn)
            ammoBitmap.x = p2Bitmap.x + (p2Bitmap.image.width * SCALE_X / 2);
            ammoBitmap.y = p2Bitmap.y;
            shotVelocity = new createjs.Point(
                Math.random() * (-4 * SCALE_X) - 3,
                Math.random() * (-3 * SCALE_Y) - 1);
            fireShot();
        }

    }

    // triggered by MSPointerDown event
    function beginAim(event)
    {
        if (playerTurn == 1)
        {
            if (!isAiming)
            {
                aimStart = new createjs.Point(event.x, event.y);
                isAiming = true;
            }
        }
    }


    // triggered by MSPointerMove event
    function adjustAim(event)
    {
        if (isAiming)
        {
            var aimCurrent = new createjs.Point(event.x, event.y);
            aimVector = calculateAim(aimStart, aimCurrent);
            // TODO write text and/or show aiming arrow on screen
            Debug.writeln("Aiming..." + aimVector.x + "/" + aimVector.y);
        }
    }

    // triggered by MSPointerUp event
    function endAim(event)
    {
        if (isAiming) {
            isAiming = false;
            var aimCurrent = new createjs.Point(event.x, event.y);
            aimVector = calculateAim(aimStart, aimCurrent);
            playerFire = true;
        }
    }

    function calculateAim(start, end)
    {
        // this only works for player 1
        var aim = new createjs.Point(
            (end.x - start.x) / 80,
            (end.y - start.y) / 80);
        aim.x = Math.min(MAX_SHOT_POWER, aim.x); // cap velocity
        aim.x = Math.max(0, aim.x); // fire forward only
        aim.y = Math.max(-MAX_SHOT_POWER, aim.y);/// cap velocity
        aim.y = Math.min(0, aim.y); // fire up only
        return aim;

    }



    function checkHit(target)
    {
        // EaselJS hit test doesn't factor in scaling
        // so use simple bounding box vs center of rock

        // get centre of rock
        var shotX = ammoBitmap.x + ammoBitmap.image.width / 2;
        var shotY = ammoBitmap.y + ammoBitmap.image.height / 2;

        // return wether center of rock is in rectangle bounding target player
        return (((shotX > target.x) &&
            (shotX <= target.x + (target.image.width * SCALE_X)))
            &&
            ((shotY >= target.y) &&
            (shotY <= target.y + (target.image.height * SCALE_Y))));
    }

    function fireShot()
    {
        playSound(FIRE_SOUND_FILE);
        ammoBitmap.visible = true;
        isShotFlying = true;
    }

    function processHit()
    {
        playSound(EXPLODE_SOUND_FILE);
        isShotFlying = false; // stop shot
        ammoBitmap.visible = false; // hide shot
        playerTurn = playerTurn % 2 + 1; // change player

        if ((player1Lives <= 0) || (player2Lives <= 0)) {
            endGame();
        }
    }

    function endGame()
    {
        Ticker.setPaused(true); // stop game loop

        // show win/lose graphic
        var endGameImage;
        if (player1Lives <= 0)
        {
            playSound(LOSE_SOUND_FILE);
            endGameImage = preload.getResult("loseImage").result;

        }
        else if (player2Lives <= 0)
        {
            endGameImage = preload.getResult("winImage").result;
            playSound(WIN_SOUND_FILE);
        }
        var endGameBitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(endGameImage);
        stage.addChild(endGameBitmap);
        endGameBitmap.x = (canvas.width / 2) - (endGameImage.width * SCALE_X / 2);
        endGameBitmap.y = (canvas.height / 2) - (endGameImage.height * SCALE_Y / 2);
        endGameBitmap.scaleX = SCALE_X;
        endGameBitmap.scaleY = SCALE_Y;
        stage.update();
    }

    function draw() {
        // EaselJS allows for easy updates
        stage.update();
    }

    function playSound(path)
    {
        var sound = document.createElement("audio");
        sound.src = path;
        sound.autoplay = true;
    }

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
        // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
        // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the
        // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
        // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
        // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
        // args.setPromise().
    };

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialize, false);
    app.start();
})();
```

And there is the problem: when I'm trying to build this game, I'm getting error like this:

*0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action*

in the marked place in my code

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Can you try pass canvas id to cretejs.Stage like var stage = new createjs.Stage("gameCanvas"); ? http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Stage.html

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but unfortunatelly, I'm getting the same error :(. Don't know why but I did everything what tutorial says, searched in google, but nothing.

Comment: What if you load default.js after other files. As I see, now you are loading it before easeljs-0.6.0.min.js and preloadjs-0.2.0.min.js

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but again, unfortunately, nothing changed. I'm getting the same error, even though I moved default.js after easyljs and createjs files.

Comment: Oh my God! I just realised, that I havent such version as "easeljs-0.6.0.min.js" in my Project Files Panel. I moved my existing one "easeljs-0.5.0.min.js" and error disappear, but now I get another error saying "
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'addChild' of undefined or null reference" in this "stage.addChild(bgBitmap);" line (line 100). I'm worst programmer in the world :D

Comment: Please check to have fully included the resources in the project, folders and subfolder of images and sounds

Comment: Looks like everything is set up properly, I have all the images, folders, subfolders, sounds. This is my errors:

APPHOST9623: The app couldn’t resolve ms-appx://881e8819-bb5c-496a-aa21-0293bca33266/images/Catapults/Red/redFire/redCatapultFire.png because of this error: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND.(<----- I get this line 4 times)




SCRIPT5007: Unhandled exception at line 100, column 9 in ms-appx://881e8819-bb5c-496a-aa21-0293bca33266/js/default.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'addChild' of undefined or null reference
File: default.js, Line: 100, Column: 9

Comment: @DeimantsBrandišausks You miss the resource { id: "redFire", src: "images/Catapults/Red/redFire/redC‌​atapultFire.png" } in the project as the message report and, I think, that miss break the script. Put the resource in the correct folder and try.

Comment: But I have everything set up correctly - >> http://postimg.org/image/4b1orth17/ . 
Here is the error I'm getting ->> http://s14.postimg.org/9tlzoutrl/Untitled.png
In any case, big thanks for your help, I appreciate that.

Comment: @DeimantsBrandišausks It seems ok, there is images/background/gameplay_screen.png? I see that the example is build on easeljs0.4 not in 0.5 cany you try change it?

Comment: Yes, I have that gameplay_screen.png file in the right directory. I changed everything to "easeljs-0.5.0.min.js" (http://s24.postimg.org/aw0plrebp/Untitled.png), and getting same eror. 

If I comment this line(stage.addChild(bgBitmap);) then I'm getting error on the other line (stage.addChild(p1Bitmap);) . 

Seems like my project just can't get resources :/

Comment: Check the console on Firebug and the network tab, see any error? Try to downgrade to easeljs 0.4 (just to test)

Comment: No errors at all. And downgrade also doesn't work. Thank you for helping me, I appreciate that. I would give you a reputation point if I would know how to do that :)

Comment: Try access one resource directly by typing the direct url, it works? For the rep i'll teach you how it works :-)

Comment: change `var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);` to `stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);`. You are creating the new stage in the wrong scope.

Comment: Like this ? { id: "screenImage", src: "gameplay_screen.png" }, 

Doesn't work.

Comment: @bmceldowney WOW! It works !!! Amazing. Thank you very much :). Both of you, appreciate that :)

How to give you both reputation? I'm kinda new in this awesome forum :/

Comment: To thank other user you can mark answer as correct, or upvote other answer (with the minimal reputation required, 15 I think) read the FAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three problems, I report them from previous comments:

- easeljs not present in the correct folder
- mages/Catapults/Red/redFire/redC‌​atapultFire.png missing
- change `var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);` to `stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);` you don't have to instantiate that variable as reported in the tutorial (http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-simple-windows-8-game-with-javascript-game-basics-createjseaseljs/)

And close this other related question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16101960/975520), I think is solved by posting your solution as answer.